# In .NET 4, does BeginInvoke and Task use the same threadpool?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, concurrency

.NET 4 introduced a brand new thread pool design accessed by the Task Parallel library. But if I have old code that uses Delegate.BeginInvoke, will those be executed by that new thread pool? Or is the old thread pool still in the runtime somewhere?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They both use the same ThreadPool.  `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` does, as well.

However, `Delegate.BeginInvoke` has extra overhead when compared to Task.Factory.StartNew, and does not take advantages of many of the features in the ThreadPool, such as work stealing or the new debugging features.  I would recommend refactoring this to use the new Task features as time permits.